# Change UI culture in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime, culture, currentuiculture, uiculture

Is it possible to change the UI Culture in WinRT on-the-fly? I've found `ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en";`, but this only works before showing the app UI and not afterwards (e.g. I want to change the UI language through the settings).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15087075/24874

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. [An example is in the SDK resources.](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-cd0c6eaa)
There are different scenarios. Scenario 8 shows how to change language on the fly.