# Change language in runtime for W8 Application

Tags: c#, localization, winrt-xaml

I have to localize an W8 C# application.
The user must be able to change the language in runtime.

I tried to used :

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PromaryLanguageOverride = "de-DE";
```

and reload the Frame with :

```
var _Frame = Windo.Current.Content as Frame;
_Frame.Navigate(_Frame.Content.GetType());
_Frame.GoBack();
```

It had no effect in runtime but it works when I restart the application.

What can I do to make it works in runtime ?

My app had only images in folders like "en-US"; "de-DE"; "fr-FR"...

The Package.appxmanifest has this property :

```
<Ressource Language="x-generate" />
```

I already tried to specify each languages :

```
<Resources>
   <Resource Language="en-US" />
   <Resource Language="fr-FR" />
   <Resource Language="de-DE" />
</Resources>
```

but it changed nothing.

Thank's for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this, it is what you want

[Change UI culture in WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743704/change-ui-culture-in-winrt)

[Application resources and localization sample (Windows 8)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-4e08b196)

Comment: Be aware that this has to do with Windows 8.1

Comment: These samples demonstrate how to select a resource in a specific language, but it is not applied on all the app :-(

Answer (score 0):

You will need to recreate the views that you've already displayed - which is what happens when you close and restart the application.

If you start the application and change the language, **new** views will be displayed in the new language, but any views that still exist in memory will show the original text.

You have two options:

1. Automatically restart the application and redisplay the page the user was on when they changed the language.
2. Go through and recreate any existing views so they pick up the new resources.

Comment: in fact, the following views are not affected by the language update. I actualy need to restart the app.